# Travelling in the EU with an expired visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, europe, transit-visas, turkish-citizens

I am studying as a full-time student in Latvia. We have already booked our flights for Christmas to Germany between December 21 and January 4. But the Latvian government prolonged my application for a residence permit.

Therefore, I do not have a residence permit right now, but I have a paper that says I can stay in Latvia until February 14 (Document written in Latvian). I was wondering if I can fly to Germany and come back to Latvia with my expired visa by plane.

It would be a disappointing Christmas for us if I could not be there.  I am waiting for your answers, thanks.

I am a Turkish citizen.

Comment: Please provide your nationality.

Comment: I am Turkish...

Comment: Dont go to Germany without your Latvia residence permit. Yes you can stay in Latvia with the latvian document but not visit Germany. Germany has enforced border checks, so if they catch you without proper documents, they will ban you from Germany. Most likely the airline will not board you.

Comment: @pbu Since Latvia is a member of Schengen agreement there should be no border checks on flights between Latvia and Germany.

Comment: @Neusser True but risky. The OP does not have a valid EU travel document. Germany and France have enforced border checks because of attacks during christmas time. see: https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/reintroduction-border-control_en

Comment: @pbu "Land border from Austria and flight connections from Greece".